# Chrome version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) not supporting Nudi 4.0

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, webfonts, kannada

Chrome version 61.0.3163.100 does not support the kannada font. I am using Nudi 4.0 Software to feed data in the kannada font, but Chrome and Internet Explorer are not supporting. **Firefox Version 54.0.1 (32-bit)** *does* support it. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: You will need to provide more detail. What is Nudi? Also, go ahead and give up on something not working in IE8. That browser has been abandoned for years; no one should be using it or supporting it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TylerH. We have web application, in that web form need to key-in data in "Kannada language" so we are using "Nudi 4.0" software to key-in data in "Kannada font". In browsers like IE, Firefox and Chrome are working fine in earlier days but now Firefox only support to feed data in "Kannada font" and rest not supporting.